# What efficient Java collection would be used to store a million strings?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any specific API which needs to be used? Could someone please post how it could be implemented.

Any suggestion would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you want to do with the Strings? Will there be a lot of inserts, removals, iterations, searches?

Comment: In addition to @Keppil's qestions, how long are the strings?

Comment: why do you want to load million records in memory ? Consider to load them in chunks and then you can use List/Set collection api.

Comment: Or even using an embedded java db. There are plenty out there, and they'll take care of the memory management and caching for you.

Answer (score 5):

This will depend upon your requirement which collection would be suitable, If it is list of String then use `java.util.List` or if it is set of String then use `java.util.Set` or it is also key-value pair then use `Map`.

And implementation of each interface also specific to requirement.

When you are talking about data amount then it comes with two things:

1. performance
2. memory.

Talking on performance if it is ArrayList - The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires `O(n)` time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking).The constant factor is low compared to that for the `LinkedList` implementation.
In case of `HashSet` it also offers constant time performance for the basic operations (`add, remove, contains and size`), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

`HashMap` provides constant-time performance `O(1)` for the basic operations (`get and put`).

And Talking on memory if large collection goes run out of memory that means if you get `OutOfMemoryExcaption`. Then you must increase you heap space by passing `-Xmxn`.

> **-Xmx***n*
>       Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is 64MB. The upper limit for this value will be approximately 4000m on Solaris 7 and Solaris 8 SPARC platforms and 2000m on Solaris 2.6 and x86 platforms, minus overhead amounts. like -Xmx2048m

Comment: Good reply—in addition, if there are duplicate strings use `String.intern()` to save memory. Two interned strings with the same content share their memory.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further information of contexts and frequent operations, it seems best to use simple string array or embedded java DB.