# List of Strings VS String Array VS Stringbuilder

Tags: java

Which is the best one to choose to store list of string on the basis of performance.

Which one offers the best performance.

Thanks.

Comment: performance wise arrays are good. But list gives you advance features which array can not provide.

Comment: Define "performance".  Space, speed, reliability?  How many Strings are we talking about?

Comment: You can check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639712/what-efficient-java-collection-would-be-used-to-store-a-million-strings

Comment: -1, A StringBuilder is s different data sbructure (and used for different purposes) compared to an Array or List. And as has already been mentioned you haven't defined what performance means to you so the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a good general purpose `List` and will usually out-perform an `Array` or `LinkedList`. Here is the breakdown in terms of time complexity (`V` is the type, `i` is an index):

```
       Type | add(V) | remove(V) | get(i) | 
-------------------------------------------
      Array |  O(n)  |    O(n)   |  O(1)  |
  ArrayList |  O(1)  |    O(n)   |  O(1)  |
 LinkedList |  O(1)  |    O(1)   |  O(n)  |
```

In general you can use this rule:

**Array:** Use if you *know* the exact number of elements and don't need to add or remove elements.

**List:** Use if you *don't know* the exact number of elements and need to add or remove elements.

`StringBuilder` is completly different. `StringBuilder` is a mutable String. You can think of it as `List<Character>`. In that sense, it is probably not what you need so to compare it to `List<String>` or `String[]` is probably not benificial.

Comment: Clear and concise. Great answer

Answer (score 2):

List of String literals before java 7 will just consume your permgen Area which may led to JVM crash. So if you have too many String better go for Stringbuilder. Stringbuilder internally uses char array. However using Stringbuilder for storing list of String you may have to use special character for separation and then split() to retrieve back your list.

Better alternative would be to go for an String array. As mentioned earlier even Stringbuilder uses an char array. So if you are sure you want to store list of String this would be good option. But if this is the only goal I would say why not use ArratList... you don't have to bother about the size of the array.

Comment: How would you access individual Strings in a StringBuilder? A StringBuilder is s different data sbructure compared to and Array or List.

Comment: Well one way would be to append all String with special character and to get the List you can do something like sbuilder.toString().split(SpChar). You will get arrays of String.

Comment: So now you have to parse the data to access it and then you would have the data stored in two places, once in the StringBuilder and once in the Array. Doesn't seem very efficient to me from a performance point of view.

Comment: Agreed it is better to use String array. Infact as I specified Stringbuilder uses char array as it internal DS.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `StringBuilder` when constructing large strings. Although the speed difference is not noticeable, this is the most efficient.

I've also heard somewhere that Java uses a builder internally when you use the plus operator on strings. Although I'm uncertain, it is highly unlikely.

Comment: Java Compiler does replace concatenated strings with a `new StringBuilder().append(first).append(second)...` construct (or `StringBuffer`?). You can see it first hand when you decompile a class with string concatenation.

Comment: @Cebence Hmm, so how does it decide whether to use buffer or builder?

Comment: `StringBuffer?` meant maybe it's that one, I am not sure which one. It might depend on the compiler, but it always uses the same one.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is an immutable class, it can't be changed. `StringBuilder` is a mutable class that can be appended to, characters replaced or removed and ultimately converted to a `String`.

Note that if you are using Java 5 or newer, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. From the API documentation:

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

For [More](http://kaioa.com/node/59)

Answer (score 0):

- String array can use when you are going to specified size of data. **String array
  is not growable.**
- Collection classes is used when your data is **growable**. It means that
  if your array size will vary dynamically or runtime, at that time you can use it.
- StringBuilder is not used to storing list of data.It appends string data like String buffer. If
  you search the difference between String VS StringBuffer Vs String
  Builder, you can get idea